# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'amazon web server path' shows wrong path

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.7

We are building up website in magento. it was working well until last night. But when i merged with the other programmer. I am having this issue.

It gives me this error "**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'amazon web server' (4)**".

I know its problem of database path and it can resolved by changing path into `app/etc/config.xml` . But it shows me **localhost**  as a host name.

I was using localhost at first and it was working.

I am not sure why this is happening.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to give IP instead of localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed path in app/etc/local.xml, and now it's working.  Before it was pointing to amazon web server, i changed it to localhost.